# Big nth prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

I know the following nth prime numbers:

$n = 10 \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 29$
$n = 10 ^ 2 \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 541$
$n = 10 ^ 3 \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 7,919$
$n = 10 ^ 4 \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 104,729$
$n = 10 ^ 5 \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 1,299,709$
$n = 10 ^ 6 \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 15,485,863$
$n = 10 ^ 7 \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 179,424,673 $
$n = 10 ^ 8 \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 2,038,074,743$
$n = 10 ^ 9 \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 22,801,763,489 $
$n = 10 ^ {10} \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 252,097,800,623$
$n = 10 ^ {11} \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 2,760,727,302,517$
$n = 10 ^ {12} \longrightarrow n$th prime $= 29,996,224,275,833$

Anyone knows where I can find the nth prime numbers for the following values on 'n'?

$n = 10 ^ {13} \longrightarrow n$th prime $=$
$n = 10 ^ {14} \longrightarrow n$th prime $=$
$n = 10 ^ {15} \longrightarrow n$th prime $=$
$n = 10 ^ {16} \longrightarrow n$th prime $=$
$n = 10 ^ {17} \longrightarrow n$th prime $=$
$n = 10 ^ {18} \longrightarrow n$th prime $=$
$n = 10 ^ {19} \longrightarrow n$th prime$=$
$n = 10 ^ {20} \longrightarrow n$th prime $=$
etc ...

Comment: B-file at OEIS sequence [A006988](https://oeis.org/A006988) has up to $n=24$.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for!